# Mongoose and GraphQL filtering best approach

Tags: typescript, mongoose, graphql

I would like to add a filtering option to my project (GraphQL + Mongoose).

Currently my POC looks like below, but it has a very serious disadvantage that for each field I have to add a lot of filtering stuff and it makes the whole code very complicated.

Do you have any ideas or experiences on how it can be done better?

**Resolver**

```
//FindAll
@Query(() => [Customer])
@Roles({roles: ['user']})
async customers(@Args('filters') customersFiltersInput: CustomersFiltersInput) {
  const customers = await this.customerService.findAll(customersFiltersInput);
  return customers;
}
```

**Service**

```
async findAll(
  customersFiltersInput: CustomersFiltersInput,
): Promise<Customer[]> {
  var filters: any = {};

  if (customersFiltersInput.customerTypes) {
    filters.customerType =
      customersFiltersInput.customerTypesFilteringOption ===
      FilterOptionList.In
        ? { $in: customersFiltersInput.customerTypes }
        : { $nin: customersFiltersInput.customerTypes };
  }
  if (customersFiltersInput.name) {
    if (customersFiltersInput.nameFilteringOption == FilterOptionText.Equals)
      filters.name = { $eq: customersFiltersInput.name };
    if (
      customersFiltersInput.nameFilteringOption == FilterOptionText.NotEquals
    )
      filters.name = { $ne: customersFiltersInput.name };
  }

 //...
 //...
 //Mainly here the code will grow if additional fields come to Customer - right?

  const query = this.customerModel.find(filters);
  return await query.exec();
}
```

**Input**

```
@InputType()
export class CustomersFiltersInput {
    @Field(() => [CustomerType, {nullable: true}])
    public readonly customerTypes?: [CustomerType];

    @Field(() => FilterOptionList, {nullable: true, defaultValue: FilterOptionList.In})
    public readonly customerTypesFilteringOption: FilterOptionList

    @Field({nullable: true})
    public readonly name?: String;

    @Field(() => FilterOptionText, {nullable: true, defaultValue: FilterOptionText.Equals})
    public readonly nameFilteringOption: FilterOptionText
}
```

**Filter option for Lists**

```
import { registerEnumType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

export enum FilterOptionList {
  In = 'In',
  NotIn = 'NotIn',
}

registerEnumType(FilterOptionList, {
  name: 'FilterOptionList',
});
```

**Filter option for Text**

```
import { registerEnumType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

export enum FilterOptionText {
  Equals = 'Equals',
  NotEquals = 'NotEquals',
  Like = 'Like',
  NotLike = 'NotLike'
}

registerEnumType(FilterOptionText, {
  name: 'FilterOptionText',
});
```

**GQL query**

```
query allCustomers {
  customers(filters:{
    customerTypes: [ BUSINESS, OTHER, INDIVIDUAL],
    customerTypesFilteringOption: In,
    name: "Alice",
    nameFilteringOption: Equals
  }) {
    id, name, customerType, customerStatus,
    addresses {id, city, street, addressType }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way as below.

I am waiting for your opinions and I will leave it for others - maybe it will be useful to someone...

**Filter option types**

```
import { registerEnumType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

export enum FilterOption {
  Equals = 'Equals',
  NotEquals = 'NotEquals',
  Contains = 'Contains',
  NotContains = 'NotContains',
  In = 'In',
  NotIn = 'NotIn',
}

registerEnumType(FilterOption, {
  name: 'FilterOption',
});
```

**Filter input (aggregates the filter when multiple filters)**

```
import { Field, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { FilterItemInput } from './filter-item.input';

@InputType()
export class FilterInput {
    @Field(() => [FilterItemInput])
    public readonly items?: [FilterItemInput];
}
```

**Filter item (miltiple filtering)**

```
import { Field, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { FilterOption } from '../enums/filter-option';

@InputType()
export class FilterItemInput {
    @Field()
    public readonly fieldName?: String;

    @Field()
    public readonly value?: String;

    @Field(() => FilterOption)
    public readonly filterOption: FilterOption
}
```

**Resolver**

```
//FindAll
@Query(() => [Customer])
@Roles({roles: ['user']})
async customers(@Args('filter') filter: FilterInput) {
  const customers = await this.customerService.findAll(filter.items);
  return customers;
}
```

**Service**

```
async findAll(filters: [FilterItemInput]): Promise<Customer[]> {
  
  var findFilters: Array<any> = [];

  if(filters) {
    filters.forEach((filter) => {
      if(filter.filterOption == FilterOption.Equals)
        findFilters.push({[`${filter.fieldName}`] : {$eq: filter.value}})
      if(filter.filterOption == FilterOption.NotEquals)
        findFilters.push({[`${filter.fieldName}`] : {$ne: filter.value}})
      if(filter.filterOption == FilterOption.Contains)
        findFilters.push({[`${filter.fieldName}`] : {$regex: '.*' + filter.value, $options: 'i'}})
      if(filter.filterOption == FilterOption.NotContains)
        findFilters.push({[`${filter.fieldName}`] : { $not: {$regex:'.*' + filter.value + '.*', $options: 'i'} }})      
      if(filter.filterOption == FilterOption.In)
        findFilters.push({[`${filter.fieldName}`] : { $in: filter.value.split(',') }})
      if(filter.filterOption == FilterOption.NotIn)
        findFilters.push({[`${filter.fieldName}`] : { $nin: filter.value.split(',') }})
    })
  }

  const filter = findFilters.reduce((a, v) => ({...a, ...v}), {});
  const query = this.customerModel.find(filter);
  return await query.exec();
}
```

**Query example**

```
query allCustomers {
  customers(filter:{
    items: [
            {  
              fieldName: "name",
              value: "John,Alice,Johny,Robert",
              filterOption: In
            },
            {  
              fieldName: "surname",
              value: "d",
              filterOption: Contains
            },
            {  
              fieldName: "customerType",
              value: "BUSINESS",
              filterOption: Equals
            },
        
    ]
  }) {
    id, name, surname, customerType, customerStatus,
    addresses {id, city, street, addressType }
  }
}
```

**Searching results**

```
{
  "data": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "id": "62daea0e2cddf6617044f0c2",
        "name": "Alice",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "customerType": "BUSINESS",
        "customerStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "addresses": []
      },
      {
        "id": "62dd5a7b25d2eb85ccf2db88",
        "name": "Johny",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "customerType": "BUSINESS",
        "customerStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "addresses": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```