# Javascript convert array to object to use in Find in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I'm trying to do a dynamic filter building for a search in Mongoose.

I got an array containing various filters, and I would like to use them in this.mySchema.find ({QUERY}) as follows:

```
[
  { name: { '$eq': 'John' } },
  { surname: { '$regex': '.*t', '$options': 'i' } }
]
```

Now I would like to search by all filters as below

```
const query = this.customerModel.find(findFilters);
```

But I am getting the error below

**Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got [object Object],[object Object]**

I tried converting this to an object, but I'm getting something that I can't use either

```
{ ...findFilters }
```

Result:

```
{
  '0': { name: { '$eq': 'John' } },
  '1': { surname: { '$regex': '.*t', '$options': 'i' } }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
const result = {};
findFilters.forEach(e => result[e] = {});
```

But I got something that also doesn't work in Find and the filters don't work during the search

```
{ '[object Object]': {} }
```

So, how can I use my array of filters in the Find method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to a single object:

```js
const filters = [
  { name: { '$eq': 'John' } },
  { surname: { '$regex': '.*t', '$options': 'i' } }
];

const filter = filters.reduce((a, v) => ({...a, ...v}), {});

console.log(filter);
```

Comment: I used your help to answer my own question in another thread and to share my solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101686/mongoose-and-graphql-filtering-best-approach/73106968#73106968

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an pending promise

you need to use an async function and use `await`:

```
const query = await this.customerModel.find(findFilters);
```

Or `.then()`

```
this.customerModel.find(findFilters).then(res => {
   console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: I have the await in the next line
return await query.exec();

Comment: @g_m you dont posted it

Comment: True, since I was focused on the Find and filtering, but yes you are right regarding to the mongoose and the async/await. Thank you

Comment: I put the (almost) complete code in answer to my own question in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101686/mongoose-and-graphql-filtering-best-approach  I will be glad if you have any suggestions for my solution that I shared there...